# Two Line Header with Two font sizes using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer

I'm trying to use fancyhdr to make a multiple line header with the following format:[image]

I have searched google and this site for 15 hours with no solution

Note that in the image, the font size of the first line of the header is higher than the font size of the second line.

Also note that in the image, the font on both line of the header is faint compare to the main text.

MY MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{Anale. Seria Informatica. Vol. XVI fasc.1-2018\\Anale. Computer Science Series $16^{th}$ Tome $1^{st}$ Fasc. -2018}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\headrule{\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize height 5pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize   
\end{minipage}\par}%


\begin{document}
headers alone, no footer.
\end{document}
```

I what the following:

1. I want first line of the header to have a bigger font size than the second line on the header.
2. I want the fonts on both lines of the header and the header rules to be faint than the text in the body of the document.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution I can provide in my MWE

```
    \documentclass{article}    
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[C]{XXXXXXX. XXXXX XXXX. YYYYY. YYY YYYY. ZZZZZZ\\ {\small xxxx. 
    xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx $16^{th}$ Tome $1^{st}$ Fasc. -2018}}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \renewcommand\headrule{\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
    \hrule width \hsize height 3pt \kern 0.3mm \hrule width \hsize   
    \end{minipage}\par}%
    \begin{document}
    this is how I can go
    \end{document}
```